# Why are US mobile numbers disabled in Twilio?

Tags: twilio

If I try to purchase a phone number and select United States, the "Mobile" option becomes greyed out. Why is this? I'm able to purchase a mobile number in the United Kingdom.

I'm a resident of the United States if it makes any difference.

As a follow-up question, if I port my actual US mobile number to Twilio, will it remain a Mobile number or will it turn into a VoIP number?

Answer (score 2):

The US doesn't differentiate between mobile and non mobile numbers like some other countries do.  You can port mobile to landline and landline to mobile.